# Exporting geodatabase attribute tables to MySQL database using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mysql, odbc

I've already created a **mysql** db connection using **ODBC** and tested it. Now I want to *export* the attribute tables data from *ArcMap* to **mysql** which is on my localhost. On export there are many options like export (To CAD, To Shapefile, To Dbase ..) when I click on any of these no data is going to **mysql** database.

How can I export **geodatabase** data(no spatial data) to mysql database in ArcMap ?

Comment: Try using the Table to Table tool?

Answer (score -1):

Try this : 
ogr2ogr facility to convert shape file directly to MySQL Database

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39591499/extract-country-specific-openstreetmap-extract-into-mysql-spatial-table

Comment: Link-only answers are automatically flagged for deletion. Please summarize the content in the linked answer in your answer, or it may be deleted.